# Ubuntu 20.04 Dell desktop won’t load into boot menu

Tags: grub2, password, password-recovery

I just received a dell desktop with Ubuntu 20.04 i went through the initial process of setting it up, but i forgot my password, i’m trying to reset the password by going in the boot menu by pressing and holding shift but nothing is happening, this is the first time i’ve even used an Ubuntu software

Comment: see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/16049/1698042